# Circular reasoning in proof of linearity and boundedness of operator

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, operator-theory

> Let $\{e_k\}_{k = 1}^\infty$ be the basis of $\ell^2$. Define $T \colon \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ as follows:
>   $$Te_k = \frac1k(e_k + e_{k + 1}),\qquad\forall k \geq 1$$
>   Prove that $T$ is a linear and bounded operator.

At first I thought that defining $T$ over the basis elements would be enough, but I got immediately stuck when trying to find the image of an arbitrary element $x \in \ell^2$:
$$Tx = T\left(\sum_{k = 1}^\infty x_k e_k\right) = T\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^n x_k e_k\right) =\ ?? \tag1$$

The solution says:
$$Tx = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty x_k\frac{e_k + e_{k + 1}}k = (x_1, x_1 + \frac{x_2}2, \frac{x_2}2 + \frac{x_3}3, \ldots) \tag2$$
which is clearly linear and then proceeds to note that $T$ is the sum of two bounded operators and hence is bounded.

I really don't understand how we can go from $(1)$ to $(2)$ without requiring at least linearity and continuity, which is what we have to prove?! What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you try to show that  $T$ is onto?

Comment: @NiklasHebestreit I am not. But to prove linearity, $T(\alpha x + \beta y) = \alpha Tx + \beta Ty$, we have to know how the operator behaves on an arbitrary element in $\ell^2$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T$ is well-defined on $E= \mathrm{span} \{ e_k \}_k$, which is a dense subspace of $\ell^2$. The restriction $$T|_E :E \longrightarrow \ell^2$$ is continuous on $E$ since it is the sum of two bounded operators (on $E$).

Hence, $T|_E$ can be extended to a unique bounded operator $T$ defined on $\bar{E}= \ell^2$.

Comment: I see. Do you have a link to a proof of this theorem?

Comment: Here there is the statement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_linear_extension but no proof.

Comment: Thanks, I found a proof [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/book/ch5.pdf) [PDF] if anyone's interested.